# Why I can't access my application inside Kubernetes cluster through tomcat server?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I'm running a kubernetes cluster with minikube on ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS. When I launch the deployments I can access the Tomcat server from the cluster, but I can't open my application, I got the error message :

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
```

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
    version: "3"

#NETWORK
networks:
  network1:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  dir-site:
    driver_opts:
      device: /smartclass_docker/site/
      type: bind
      o: bind
# Declare services
services:
  # service name
  server:
    container_name: server
    # Container image name
    image: repo/myimage
    ## Image used to build Dockerfile 
    build:
      #dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./smart/

    # Container ports and host matching
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      - "8080:8080"

    ## Startup Policy
    restart driver: bridge
volumes:
  dir-site:
    driver_opts:
      device: /smart/site/
      type: bind
      o: bind
# Declaration of services
services:
  # service name
  server:
    container_name: server
    # name of the image
    image: repo/myimage
    ## Use IMAGE BUILD DOCKERFILE
    build:
      #dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./smart/

    # CONTAINER ports
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      - "8080:8080"

    ## Startup policy
    restart: always

    # connect to network1
    networks:
      - network1
    volumes:
            - /data/dockerStore/data/db_server_1:/var/lib/mysql/

    restart: always

    # connect to network1
    networks:
      - network1
    volumes:
            - /data/dockerStore/data/db_server_1:/var/lib/mysql/
```

Here is my kubernetes deployment file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: myapp
  # type: LoadBalancer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: jksun12/vdsaipro
        command: ["/run.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 3306
        - containerPort: 9001
        - containerPort: 9002
   # volumeMounts:
   #     - name: myapp-pv-claim
   #       mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
   #   volumes:
   #   - name: myapp-pv-claim
   #     persistentVolumeClaim:
   #       claimName: myapp-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myapp-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  accesModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

My application files are in the /smart directory, which is a subdirectory of the directory where I actually run docker-compose and build my main Dockerfile.
How can I solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: How is your docker compose related to your kubernetes deployment ? As to `404` message, does it come from your Tomcat server ? Have you checked its logs ? It should tell you the exact reason of this `404` error. You should be able to see the specific path that your http request is trying to get.

Comment: Thanks, @mario I did that and I found that the errors come from the extraction of the .war file inside the container. There was also an error in the version of the tomcat server used for the application. it's solved now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I checked the logs inside the containers, and I found that the errors come from the extraction of the .war file inside the container.
There was also an error in the version of the tomcat server used for the application. So I changed the version of tomcat to another version.

It's solved now. Thanks